# Replace slash in Bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, tr, slash

Let's suppose I have this variable:

```
DATE="04\Jun\2014:15:54:26"
```

Therein I need to replace `\` with `\/` in order to get the string:

```
"04\/Jun\/2014:15:54:26"
```

I tried `tr` as follows:

```
echo "04\Jun\2014:15:54:26" | tr  '\' '\\/'
```

But this results in: `"04\Jun\2014:15:54:26"`.

It does not satisfy me. Can anyone help?

Comment: `man tr` would tell you why it doesn't work.  You could use `sed`.

Comment: Why not create DATE in that format ? Also if you are echoing and writing the date before tr/sed/ect why not write it in that format ?

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do here? Replace forward slashes with backslashes or escaping all forward slashes? This question could use some clearing up. :)

Comment: Why do you need to escape the forward slashes in the first place?

Answer (score 120):

No need to use an echo + a pipe + sed.

A simple substitution variable is enough and faster:

```
echo ${DATE//\//\\/}

#> 04\/Jun\/2014:15:54:26
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in Bash 4.2.25 -- it only replaces the first slash.

For example:

`FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot="source\scripts\components\screens\picker_view"; echo "${FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot/\\//}"` prints `source/scripts\components\screens\picker_view`

Comment: Just figured it out, and this approach does work. You need to make sure you use two forward slashes after the variable name. So, in my example, `${FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot//\\//}`. Otherwise, it just replaces the first one. Somewhat subtle...

Answer (score 16):

Use `sed` for substitutions:

```
sed 's#/#\\/#g' < filename.txt > newfilename.txt
```

You usually use "`/`" instead of the "`#`", but as long as it is there, it doesn't matter.

I am writing this on a windows PC so I hope it is right, you may have to escape the slashes with another slash.

`sed` explained, the `-e` lets you edit the file in place.  You can use `-i` to create a backup automatically.

```
sed -e s/STRING_TO_REPLACE/STRING_TO_REPLACE_IT/g index.html
```

Answer (score 9):

here you go:

```
kent$  echo "04/Jun/2014:15:54:26"|sed 's#/#\\/#g'  
04\/Jun\/2014:15:54:26
```

your `tr` line was not correct, you may mis-understand what `tr` does, `tr 'abc' 'xyz'` will change `a->x, b->y, c->z`,not changing whole `abc->xyz`..

Answer (score 9):

You can also escape the slashes, with a slightly less readable solution than with hashes:

```
echo "04/Jun/2014:15:54:26" | sed 's/\//\\\//g'
```

Answer (score 7):

This has not been said in other answers so I thought I'd add some clarifications:

`tr` uses two sets of characters for replacement, and the characters from the first set are replaced with those from the second set in a one-to-one correspondance. The manpage states that

> SET2 is extended to length of SET1 by repeating its last character as necessary.  Excess characters of SET2 are ignored.

Example:

```
echo abca | tr ab de    # produces decd
echo abca | tr a de     # produces dbcd, 'e' is ignored
echo abca | tr ab d     # produces ddcd, 'd' is interpreted as a replacement for 'b' too
```

When using `sed` for substitutions, you can use another character than '/' for the delimiter, which will make your expression clearer (I like to use ':', @n34_panda proposed '#' in their answer). Don't forget to use the `/g` modifier to replace all occurences: `sed 's:/:\\/:g'` with quotes or `sed s:/:\\\\/:g` without (backslashes have to be escaped twice).

Finally your shortest solution will probably be @Luc-Olivier's answer, involving substitution, in the following form (don't forget to escape forward slashes too when part of the expected pattern):

```
echo ${variable/expected/replacement}     # will replace one occurrence
echo ${variable//expected/replacement}    # will replace all occurrences
```